# Is there a lightning event that a component can bind to on screen rotation?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app

Is there an event that gets fired in lightning when the screen rotates? I'd like to change some properties of a component if the user rotates the screen to a landscape view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [onorientationchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange) event to do something. The code would look like this:

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        window.addEventListener(
            "orientationchange", 
            $A.getCallback(function(event) {
                // You can use component/helper here...
            })
        );
    }
})
```

Alternatively, consider using CSS media queries in your CSS:

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) { ... }
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for, I shouldn't have assumed that window was completely protected :)

Comment: @ScottMorrison Oh, it is completely protected (i.e. "filtered") in Locker Service, but you can listen to pretty much any type of window event.

Comment: @sfdcfox can you please tell how to use orientation:landscape css with lightning:layoutitem. We have attributes for smallDeviceSize etc but how to give css in a use case like when device is ipad and viewing in landscape/potrait mode. Searching for Lightning:layoutItem's native solution rather than specifying any customization

Comment: @MonalisaDas I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to ask. You might want to simply ask a new question so we can see all the code you've tried so far and what you're attempting to accomplish.